# Beginners Python List Error: "List indices must be integers, not str"?

Tags: python-2.7

```
attributes = [["strength", 0], ["health", 0], ["wisdom", 0], ["dexterity", 0]]
attrib = raw_input("Which attribute would you like to add these points to? ")
int(attrib)
print attributes[attrib][1]
```

**output:**

```
List indices must be integers, not str
```

I want attrib to be the number that the user enters. I don't know why I'm getting this error because it seems to me that I have converted the string to an integer on line 3.

I'm guessing I am not allowed to access nested lists in this way? Lost...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int(attrib)` doesn't "modify" what's in `attrib` to an integer; it *returns* the integer. What you want is this, instead:

```
attrib = int(attrib)
```